# Display some data of database in line graph

Tags: php, mysql, graph

i wanna asking about how to display some new data in line graph?
i had tried " Select time, watt from listrik order by time DESC limit 30", it's success and display me the data on line graph as what i want, but the new data came from the left of graph. so my graph ran from right side to the left side. 
i want my new data come from the right side. so my graph run from left to the right side

my question is, can you tell me how to make it happen? or give me clue of it

sorry for my english
and thanks for answering

Comment: source code please.

Comment: try change time ASC.

Comment: i had tried it too sir, but the output just show 30 old data

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
 die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

$query = sprintf("SELECT time,watt FROM listrik ORDER BY time DESC limit 50");

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
 $data[] = $row; }

$result->close();
$mysqli->close();

print json_encode($data);

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess without seeing any junk of code, but apparently you need to swap the X axis of your grid.

I mean,  the first position of X axis should became the last one, and so on

Comment: Thanks for answering sir, can you give me suggestion or example to do it sir?

Comment: There's a built-in function to do that $reversed = array_reverse($input);